# how to bind `<prefix>+,` to F5?

Tags: tmux

I want that `F5` be an alias to `<prefix>+,` which is the `rename window` action in tmux.

I tried:

```
bind -n F5 rename-window
```

but tmux is angry when it reads the conf file.

how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `bind-key -n F5 command-prompt -I "rename-window "` on your ~/.tmux.conf and then source it. (press `Ctrl+b :` and write `source-file ~/.tmux.conf`)